# checkbox size in safari?

Tags: css, safari, checkbox

```
<style>  
input.checkbox  
{  
    width:300px;  
    height:300px;  
    margin:0px 0 0 0px;  
}  
</style>  
<body>  
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
```

Iwant to increase the checkbox size, but this code is properly work in Internet Explorer, but not in Safari.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    -webkit-transform: scale(3,3);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working any more. I'm using Safari Version 13.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You have to scale them with a custom webkit css property:

```
input.checkbox {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3,1.3);
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, that's why.  It will only work on input tags with a class of textbox.  @Styler's answer is correct, and works

Comment: @Steve both answers do the same thing.  Mine just uses a class selector to match OP's markup.  Styler's is definitely better though because it covers the generic case rather than this specific question.

Comment: I think they changed something in safari? This works in every browser except safari for me. using `-webkit` prefix and using `[type=checkbox]` selector does nothing for me. Though I did notice a *tiny* increase when setting `font-size: 200%`.

Answer (score 0):

Tutorialspoint has a better answer: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-set-checkbox-size-in-html-css

```css
      input[type=checkbox] {
         -webkit-appearance: none;
         display: inline-block;
         width: 40px;
         height: 40px;
         background-color: red;
         border-radius: 5px;
         border: 3px solid lightgray;
         margin-right: 10px;
      }
      input[type=checkbox]:checked {
         background-color: lightgreen;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

For future people, the solution is correct, however (as far as I can tell, I may be wrong about this) `transform` is no longer under the `-webkit` prefix!

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    transform: scale(3,3);
}
```